# How to write string to csv that contain escape chars?

Tags: python, string, csv

I am trying to write a list of strings to csv using csv.writer.

```
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(some_text)
```

However, some of the strings contain a random escape character, which seems to be causing  the following error : **_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set**

I've tried using the escapechar option in csv.writer like the following

```
writer = csv.writer(f, escapechar='\\')
```

but this seems to be a partial solution, since all the newline characters(\n) are not recognized.

How would I solve this problem? An example of a problematic string would be the following:

```
problem_string = "this \n sentence \% is \n problematic \g"
```

Comment: please provide a minimal working example (so that someone can just copy and paste a snippet and run it)

Comment: The argument to `writerow()` should be a list of fields, not a single string. That will write each character as a field in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

What format do you want to achieve in the end? Writing this to a csv seems to be leading to some odd outcomes anyway.

In any case, both of these code work for me without errors, both giving slightly different results with respect to escape characters.

With normal string:

```
import csv

with open('test2.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    problem_string = "this \n sentence \% is \n problematic \g"
    csvwriter.writerow(problem_string)
```

With raw input:

```
import csv

with open('test2.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    problem_string = r"this \n sentence \% is \n problematic \g"
    csvwriter.writerow(problem_string)
```